# Why does Cinnamon use so much CPU while idle?

Tags: cinnamon, cpu-usage

I'm running Linux Mint (20) Cinnamon, and while idle it uses much more CPU than Linux Mint Mate and other distros. An `htop` reveals:

[image: htop showing high-CPU usage Cinnamon process]

It's usually not this high, but nevertheless higher than it seems it needs to be.

I've tried various `ps` commands, and `cat /proc/2865/status` but none show me anything I can tell provides any information about what this process is doing.

How can I find out what is it doing? Do you have any idea what it might be doing, and how can I reduce the CPU usage?

Comment: I like Cinnamon a lot but unfortunately [it does currently fall behind many other DEs in terms of performance](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/dg87jp). Historically, KDE was that way once and after much effort on improvement, KDE Plasma now has a similar memory footprint to xfce. Cinnamon would need similar efforts to make similar gains. In the mean time, you might be able to eek out a little more performance by disabling certain themes/visual effects/etc (I have not done this myself and can't provide any useful tips here - that's why only a comment and not an answer).

Comment: Thanks, @zpangwin. Your confirmation of my suspicion is very helpful. These days I am happily using KDE (Kubuntu) and feel no need for Cinnamon, so I won't be trying any workarounds for now.

Comment: So no answers on this.  It's always hovering around 2% on my system.  I'm suspecting the wifi notifier.